# search filter with key value tabs

Tags: jquery, html, search, filter

I have got a requirement to build a search filter like as we see in Aws console.

In Aws Console I have seen a search filter where user upon clicking onto the textfield a drop down list showing the column fields for selection. on giving the value for search it will be added as a tag within the textfield like as shown below.

Can anyone tell me the name of this component. Do we have any like this available as open source for jquery, angular etc

I have created many components with basic autocomplete searching but nothing like this.

I have Bootstrap tag input (https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/) but the problem is that there I am able to select only the available tags....but in my case lets say if my table is have five columns (Name, Place, Contact, Age, Occupation). On clicking onto the textfield an autocomplete for Name, Place, Contact, Age, Occupation should come first, from which lets say I selected Name, then it should allow me to enter some value againt Name for searching and finally it should be added as a individual tag like Name:someValue

Can anyone please help me on this

[image]

Comment: I'm going to vote to close this question as it's not about programming. This is a broad question which will result in opinionated responses.
Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @ProEvilz I have described my problem

Comment: But you are still asking for recommendations of tools and thus, is off-topic. You haven't describe a **problem**, you have just described some form of functionality that you like the look of. 

**what is the PROBLEM you have here**

Comment: @ProEvilz how abt now....correct me if I am still wrong

Answer (score 1):

There are many JS plugins for this:

```
<input class="tagsinput-typeahead" type="text" />

var places = [
  {name: "New York"}, 
  {name: "Los Angeles"},
  {name: "Copenhagen"},
  {name: "Albertslund"},
  {name: "Skjern"}  
];
$('.tagsinput-typeahead').tagsinput({
  typeahead: {
    source: places.map(function(item) { return item.name }),
    afterSelect: function() {
        this.$element[0].value = '';
    }
  }
});
```

For reference check this: [Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/gm3a1s9k/1/)

Here is bootstrap plugin too:
[Click here](https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.... actually I have used this component but does not satisfies my requirement

Comment: ok, @AlexMan, let me check if I can find anything. I am sure there will be some custom changes to  be made into this plugin.